# printing a "graphics var" in my project -assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I use assembly 8086 in DOSBOX on windows.
I'm trying to print a specific "object" to my screen but it doesn't working. 
I'm tring to print a 16X16 var, for example:

```
pic1    db 4,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,4 ;**     **     **│
        db 0,4,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,4,0 ; *   ******   * │
        db 0,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,0 ; **  ******  ** │
        db 0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0 ; **    **    ** │
        db 0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0 ; **    **    ** │
        db 0,0,0,4,4,4,0,4,4,0,4,4,4,0,0,0 ;   *** **  ***  │
        db 0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0 ;      ****      │
        db 0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0 ;     ******     │
        db 0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0 ;    **    **    │
        db 0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0 ;   **      **   │
        db 0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0 ;   **      **   │
        db 0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0 ;   **      **   │
        db 0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0 ;    **    **    │
        db 0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0 ;  ****    ****  │
        db 0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0 ;  ****    ****  │
        db 0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0 ;  ****    ****  │
```

and my code for printing it goes like this:

```
    IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
include 'pic1.asm'
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
    positionX dw 1
    positionY dw 1

    color db ?


;--------------------------------------

CODESEG
; --------------------------
; Your code here - Procedures
; --------------------------
;---------------------------
    proc print
    push  cx bx  

    mov bh,0
    mov cx,[positionX]
    mov dx,[positionY]
    mov al,[color]

    mov ah,0ch                  ; the print
    int 10h

    pop  bx cx

    ret
    endp print
    ;---------------------------

start: 

    mov ax, 13h                 ;graphics mode
    int 10h

    mov si, offset pic1
    xor bx,bx


    mov cx,16d

Print_line_ofx:

    mov al, [si+bx]
    mov [color], al

    call print

    add bx,1
    add [positionX],1

    loop Print_line_ofx

    mov cx,16d
    mov [positionX],1
    add [positionY],1

    cmp [positionY],16d
    jne Print_line_ofx

; Wait for key press
    mov ah, 0h
    int 16h

; Return to text mode
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

and it doesn't even print one pixel!

I know I'm not good at programm in assembly, can someone help me and fix my code so my var will be printed to my screen?

Comment: You use `si` to point to `pic1`, but you don't save it during the `int 10h` call.

Comment: *["this function is known to destroy AX and possibly SI and DI on on some PS/2 VGA systems"](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-c.html)* - so probably push/pop also `si` just to make sure this is not cause of your problem. But anyway check in debugger, what is happening in those loops, as the code looks ok on first read... I'm tempted to push you toward some more meaningful way to draw on screen, as this way through BIOS interrupt is horribly inefficient, then again there's no obvious reason why this does not work as expected, so it would be interesting to figure out why not (before rewrite)

Comment: But actually as the first pixel is `4`, you should see at least ONE pixel even if `si` gets destroyed after first call, so there's probably some other problem also. I don't see the `ds` initialization code? Try something like `mov ax,@DATA` `mov ds,ax` before setting gfx mode? (in debugger you should see the `[ds:si+bx]` is pointing to wrong memory when doing `mov al,[si+bx]`, if `ds` is not set to data segment).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was that I didn't write 
mov ax, @DATA
 mov ds,ax 
I feel like an idiot, but thanks!